# Getting a OAuth2 authorization code that can be shared with a server

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

My Android app needs to send an authorization code to my server so that the server can use that to acquire an access token for the user's Google Drive account.  I have been trying to figure out how to acquire the authorization code and I found this in the Google API documentation ([Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)):

> This sequence starts by redirecting a browser (system browser or
>   embedded in the application as a web view) to a Google URL with a set
>   of query parameters that indicate the type of Google API access the
>   application requires. Like other scenarios, Google handles the user
>   authentication and consent, but the result of the sequence is an
>   authorization code. The authorization code is returned in the title
>   bar of the browser or as a query string parameter (depends on the
>   parameters sent in the request).
>
> After receiving the authorization code, the application can exchange
>   the code for an access token and a refresh token. The application
>   presents its client_id and client_secret (obtained during application
>   registration) and the authorization code during this exchange. Upon
>   receipt of the refresh token, the application should store it for
>   future use. The access token gives your application access to a Google
>   API.

Now I am not sure how to get this authorization code in my Android app since the Android examples I have seen seem to get the access tokens directly.  I am looking at the Android AccountManager class and it has a method getAuthToken but this seems to refer to the access token and not the authorization code.

So how does one acquire the authorization code that can be shared with a server?  If it is possible I would greatly appreciate some example code.  If this is not possible what are the possible workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [Cross-client Identity](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) document. It should keep you from needing to pass user tokens back and forth.

Comment: This looks very promising!  I'll give it a try and post back here with the results.  Thank you!  I knew there had to be a way to do this cleanly.

Comment: However, it looks like I'll have to wait a while:[Note: This policy in being rolled out gradually. For the moment, when Access Tokens, are involved, it only applies when the requested scopes include “https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login”]

Comment: Well, you could always just add that scope to the ones you really want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can actually take the access token returned by the Android AccountManager, send this to your server, then have your server make a call against the Google Drive API using that same access token - it is a bearer token and not bound to the channel that created it, so please take good care of it and only send over encrypted connections.

Documentation on how to get that access token can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

While that access token is good for immediate use, it will expire in less than 1 hour, so if you are looking for a solution that enables your backend server to have continued access to the Drive data, without the user being present at your app at the time of request, an alternate approach will be needed.

Comment: I actually tried this and it does not work.  I don't think that the access token and authorization code are the same thing.

Comment: Correct - they are not the same thing. The authorization code is returned by the web application flow and is used once-off to swap for an access token (+ refresh token if originally asked for). But I don't think that's what we're talking about here - which is portability of access tokens - if using the built-in Android AccountManager to get access tokens I wouldn't expect your code to ever see an authorization code.

Comment: But evidently the server can't use the same access token as the client.  It has to get its own, which it theoretically could if the client could share its authorization code.  It looks like the  Cross-client Identity technique gets around this but I'll have to try it to know for sure.

Comment: The access token is a bearer token - meaning that it should just work (I've used that technique in the past just fine) - that's not to say there isn't a better way - the cross-client identity is likely more elegant - I haven't looked into it yet.